# Creating a List from Text File

Tags: python

## ***Question***

Create a list called destination using the data stored in travel_plans.txt. Each element of the list should contain a line from the file that lists a country and cities inside that country. Hint: each line that has this information also has a colon : in it.

## ***travel_plans.txt***

```
This summer I will be travelling  
I will go to...  
Italy: Rome  
Greece: Athens  
England: London, Manchester  
France: Paris, Nice, Lyon  
Spain: Madrid, Barcelona, Granada  
Austria: Vienna  
I will probably not even want to come back!  
However, I wonder how I will get by with all the different languages.  
I only know English!
```

**My Code so Far**

```
file=open('travel_plans.txt','r')
lines=file.readlines()

destination=[]

for li in lines:
   val=li.strip().split(',')
   for j in val:
      if j==":":
         destination.append('li\n')
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close.

- It's better to use a context manager when dealing with files.
- You don't need a second `for` loop.

Here's what I would do:

```
with open('travel_plans.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if ':' in line:
            destinations.append(line)
```

You could make this slightly better in my opinion, by separating the country and cities into a tuple of `(country, cities)`.

```
with open('travel_plans.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if ':' in line:
            country, cities = line.split(':', 1)
            cities = [city.strip() for city in cities.split(',')]
            destinations.append((country, cities))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop will not work like this. If you split by commas, the colons will never end up in an element of their own. Instead, they'll stay attached to a country as in `England: London` Luckily, you don't need that. A for loop like

```py
for li in lines:
    if ':' in li:
        destination.append(li)
```

will do the trick for you. The `if` condition checks if there is a colon in the line, in which case, according to the description, the line will be one of the wanted ones and append it to the list accordingly

Answer (score 0):

their is also a simpler way to answer this question

```
   with open("travel_plans.txt","r") as tf:
   travel=tf.readlines()
   destination=[]
   for line in travel:
       if ":" in line:
           destination.append(line)
```

you can simply iterate through lines in travel and check if  colon ":" is present in any of the lines if it is present then it would be a destination we are looking for. Then simply append it to a destination list.
Hope this helps thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
   f = open("travel_plans.txt", "r")


   for aline in f:
      destination = aline.split()
      destination = "".join(destination)
      for char in destination:




     if char == ":":
         last_destinion = destination.split()

         print(last_destinion)


    f.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).